# Laravel force delete event on relations

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, soft-delete

I'm developing a Laravel web app using Laravel 5.2. My question is very simple... How do I listen to a forceDelete event in order to forceDelete model relations?

I've been looking around the web and S.O. for a few but all the questions/answers I've found where releted to the delete method, and also in the API documentation I haven't found very much...

In my case I have a Registry model and a RegistryDetail model

**Registry table**

```
|id|name|surname|....
```

**RegistryDetail table**

```
|id|id_registry|....
```

I've created for both this `boot` function:

```
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::deleted(function($registry) {
        // Delete registry_detail
        $registry->registryDetail->delete();
    });

    static::restored(function($registry) {
        // Restore registry_detail
        $registry->registrydetail()->withTrashed()->restore();
    });
}
```

Since both models have `SoftDeletes` the `static::deleted` function is called only when the delete() method is called. if I call a forceDelete() method the related model won't be deleted from the database.

If you need more informations let me know.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can change foreign relation to do cascade delete on delete.

Comment: I don't want to change my database structure... I prefer a softwer solution like the answer below

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `deleted` event should still fire when calling `forceDelete()`. Inside the `deleted()` event method, you can check the the `forceDeleting` protected property via `isForceDeleting()` to see if you're in a regular delete or a forced delete.

```
static::deleted(function($registry) {
    // Delete registry_detail
    if ($registry->isForceDeleting()) {
        $registry->registryDetail->forceDelete();
    } else {
        $registry->registryDetail->delete();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you @patricus, this solution solved my problem, and it was exactly what I was looking for