# Laravel 5.0 Model events

Tags: php, laravel, oop, laravel-5

A bit confused about model events behaving when using SoftDelete trait.
Which event will be fired when object will be deleted?  forceDeleted?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel force delete event on relations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34952259/laravel-force-delete-event-on-relations)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out how to implement this feature. There are forceDeleting property in SoftDeletes trait. Which indicates are model deleting soft or hard at the moment. So I need only check this property in my event handler.

Answer (score 1):

A quick glance into `laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/SoftDeletes.php` shows that SoftDeletes adds two new model events: 'restoring' and 'restored'.

Therefore, you have to listen for the standard events: 'deleting' and 'deleted'. There is no a special 'soft-deleting' kind of event. Also, there are no force deletion events, either.